# to do and doing; on a person/to a person

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I think it would be wrong ***to do*** that ***to a*** person.

or

I think it would be wrong ***doing*** that **to a** person.

*(That here means uninformed or non consented medical procedure)*

Question:

1. Does it matter if I use ***to do*** or ***doing***?
2. ***To a*** person or ***on a*** person?

Answer (score 0):

The expression is ***to do something to someone*** ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-to)):

> to treat someone in a way that harms them
>
> I’ll never forgive him for what he ***did to me***.

Your sentence

> I think it would be wrong to do that to a person.

is correct.

If you want to use the continuous form (***doing***), you could consider expressing it in this way:

> I think doing that to a person would be wrong.

Here ***doing*** functions as a noun: [doing that to a person] is the subject of the verb [would be wrong].